# How to express the set of all ternary strings of odd length as regular expression?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I know that the lanuguage of all strings of odd length `{a,b}` can be expressed as: `(a+b)((a+b)(a+b))^*`.

But what about an odd length over `(a,b,c}`?

Comment: I edited the question to make sense; please note the differences in phrasing and why they are relevant!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: In particular, why do you think you have to do something very different from the binary case?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually simple...

> `(a+b+c)((a+b+c)(a+b+c))^*`.

**Explanation**

```
It is trivial since when you can do odd length over a language with 2 symbols, then why can't it be extended??
```